# How to create a hierarchy with multiple networks in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I want to classify different pictures e.g. cats and dogs. For that I want to train a general network "A" that only classifies if the input is a cat or a dog. After that a specialized sub-network for each general class should predict the race of the dog or the cat.

I know about the functional api of keras and how I can pass the output to another layer or network but my problem is how I pass the output only to one specialized network so that after I predict the general class the only network which will be used is the corresponding special network.

So I want to build something like that in keras:

```
x = Input(shape(100,))
network_a_out = NetworkA(100)(x)
if(network_a_out == classCat)
    out = NetworkCat(100)(x) # predict special race of cat
else:
    out = NetworkDog(100)(x) # predict special race of dog
```

Is there a better way to solve that in keras without using several if/else statements?

Comment: You already asked the same question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736869/how-to-combine-multiple-neural-networks-in-keras Please do not do that.

Comment: I deleted the old question now I hope this one is easier to understand

Comment: That code wouldn't work, but also, why would you want this all in one network. You would be way better off with three separate networks, that way your features layers get new weights in the secondary networks that focus on the animals breed vs. the type of animal

Comment: Did you found any solution? I need something similar for different context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the last layer(s) (which predict a dog/cat), and add a new layer to predict the race of the dog/cat. That means, use the first NN as a pretrained network to predict an animal race. 
You should train a pretrained network for dogs and other for cats.

Comment: Yes thats how I want to solve my problem but I do not know how I can make this in keras (or tensorflow) I know i can pass the output of the first NN and pass it to every specialized network but I do not know how I can pass the output only to the corresponding specialized network (without programming many if/else for every subclass)

Comment: Suppose you have stored the trained NN (which predicts dog/cat). In a new script, you load that network, remove last layers, add new layers (last layer with the size of the number of dog races) and train this pretrained net with the dog races data. After training, you can store the NN in another file.
Do the same to predict cat races.